# How to get an object from service and use if after getting it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am trying to get an object from a service and after that use the data found.

Here is my service, i am simply reading a local json file

```
myApp.service('myService', function($http) {
  this.readFile = function(file) {
    return $http.get(file).then(function(result)
    {
      return result.data;
    });
  };
});
```

I have this in my controller

```
function callService(fileName){

  var data = myService.readFile(fileName).then(function(result)
  {
      console.log(result);
      return result;
  });

  return data;

}
```

In other function that I am calling using ng-init I have this

```
 storage = callService(fileName);
    var test = storage.images;
```

The problem is that I am getting an error saying angular.js:14794

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'images' of null

After that the console print the object with the image properties

It seems that the service is being executed at the last

Comment: This is because of asynchronous execution of javascript. The service is getting executed in a new thread while the rest of your code is being executed.

Comment: Is there a way to solve that?

Comment: You can move the ng-init part of the function inside the callservice function and use that for later purposes

Comment: once a promise is always a promise. Your `storage` has to be treated like this: `storage.then((data)=>{var test = data.images;})`